# composite primary key in webSQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database in websql with a composite primary key, but i can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this statement:

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groepleden(id_groep INTEGER, id_lid INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(id_groep, id_lid)');
```

this is for an application written in jQuery Mobile, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Error message is usually helpful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groepleden
(id_groep INTEGER, id_lid INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(id_groep, id_lid))
```

Missing the last parenthesis.  You only closed the primary key arguments, not the field list.

Comment: No problem, since this fixed your problem, please mark it as the correct answer.